# include socket.io server into my html

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have run my nodeServer and Client sucessfully. But I want to connect its server to a proxy.
Here is the node client:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://localhost:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
  <script>
     var name = '';
     var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');

     // at document read (runs only ones).
     $(document).ready(function(){
        // on click of the button (jquery thing)
        // the things inside this clause happen only when 
        // the button is clicked.
        $("button").click(function(){

           // just some simple logging
           $("p#log").html('sent message: ' + $("input#msg").val());

           // send message on inputbox to server
           socket.emit('chat', $("input#msg").val() );

           // the server will recieve the message, 
           // then maybe do some processing, then it will 
           // broadcast it again. however, it will not 
           // send it to the original sender. the sender
           // will be the browser that sends the msg. 
           // other browsers listening to the server will
           // recieve the emitted message. therefore we will
           // need to manually print this msg for the sender.
           $("p#data_recieved").append("<br />\r\n" + name + ': ' + $("input#msg").val());

           // then we empty the text on the input box.
           $("input#msg").val('');
        });

        // ask for the name of the user, ask again if no name.
        while (name == '') {
           name = prompt("What's your name?","");
        }

        // send the name to the server, and the server's 
        // register wait will recieve this.
        socket.emit('register', name );
     });

     // listen for chat event and recieve data
     socket.on('chat', function (data) {

        // print data (jquery thing)
        $("p#data_recieved").append("<br />\r\n" + data.msgr + ': ' + data.msg);

        // we log this event for fun :D
        $("p#log").html('got message: ' + data.msg);

     });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="msg"></input><button>Click me</button>
  <p id="log"></p>
  <p id="data_recieved"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is Server:

```
var check="check";
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8000);

// open the socket connection
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

// listen for the chat even. and will recieve
// data from the sender.
console.log('hello nahid');
socket.on('chat', function (data) {

  // default value of the name of the sender.
  var sender = 'unregistered';
  check=sender;
  // get the name of the sender
  socket.get('nickname', function (err, name) {
     console.log('Chat message by ', name);
     console.log('error ', err);
     sender = name;
  });   

  // broadcast data recieved from the sender
  // to others who are connected, but not 
  // from the original sender.
  socket.broadcast.emit('chat', {
     msg : data, 
     msgr : sender
  });
});

// listen for user registrations
// then set the socket nickname to 
socket.on('register', function (name) {

  // make a nickname paramater for this socket
  // and then set its value to the name recieved
  // from the register even above. and then run
  // the function that follows inside it.
  socket.set('nickname', name, function () {

     // this kind of emit will send to all! :D
     io.sockets.emit('chat', {
        msg : "naay nag apil2! si " + name + '!', 
        msgr : "mr. server"
     });
  });
});


});
```

They work well together. Now I want to have included server file into another html client like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="nodeServer.js"></script>
```

In order to access variables in nodeServer.js. But The error "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined "
What can I do to solve this and also I have this line code :
    
such that it knows what socket.io syntax is. But the error exists.

What should I do to make my html file know socket.io.js.

EDIT:

The last comment on the checked answer is what solved my issue. Thanks to @Houseman.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can't just throw a Node.js file into a html DOM and expect it to work. Node.js files are run by Node.js, not by client-side html javascript.

This line  `<script src="http://localhost:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` is sufficient for loading the `io` object into your DOM, and make it accessible through javascript.

Remove this line:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="nodeServer.js"></script>`

, and you should be fine, if your server is running on port 8000. Your server code, however, doesn't seem to have the necessary components to actually run.

### EDIT:

If you want to pass variables from your client to your server, or the other way around, use sockets, just like you're already doing.

Comment: Hi, I know the essentials for having node client and node server running. They are working with no problem. I actually want to know how to access variables defined in node server in another html. I want to pass 'check' s value to another html file.

Comment: I mean that I have nodeServer.js and nodeclient.html that are working together and I added their code in question. And I have another html file called proxyClient.html that in there I have to use variables' values in nodeServer.js.

Comment: @NahidAtaei If you want to be able to access variables defined in the node server in another html, it won't work to just include the server file in the html. You'd probably need to pass those variables over sockets.

Comment: I don't know. Is it possible? How can I connect an Html and Js file using sockets with different syntax.

Comment: @NahidAtaei It's possible. You're already doing it when you do          `socket.emit('chat', $("input#msg").val() );`.   Here you're sending a socket by the name of `chat` with the value of whatever `$("input#msg").val()` is. Just do that whenever you want to send values between client and server

Comment: You see? I don't use syntax in node server for my html file. In html file(proxyclient.html not node client)I can't use socket.on('chat') in order to get value emitted. I don't know how to say. I have 3 files that two of them are working on nodejs and another one wants to access variables passed from node client to node server. And here I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @NahidAtaei communication between a client and a server is private. A third file like proxyclient.html cannot hear eavesdrop on the communication between the two. You can, however, from the server, do `io.sockets.emit('socketName', obj)` to send a socket to every connected client. So step 1: client sends data to server. Step 2: server broadcasts same data. Step 3: proxyclient.html listens to this broadcast and now knows what the client sent the server.